# Changed hyperxmp or hyperref causing error with pdfdate={\today}

Tags: hyperref, datetime2, hyperxmp

The following used to be OK. With the most recent release of `hyperxmp`, it no longer does, giving error:

```
./hypersetup-bug.tex:9: Argument of \hyxmp@pdf@to@xmp@date has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.9 }
```

How can this be fixed or worked around?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperxmp} % to add metadata info into pdf
\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfapart=2, 
  pdfaconformance=u,
  pdfdate={\today},
}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\end{document}
```

I tried changing the preamble so as to include the following:

```
\usepackage[main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime2}
```

That avoids the error. However, I still want to be able to include in the text of the document a date of a form such as "December 1, 2020". Unfortunately, `timedate2` has redefined `\today`, and I cannot figure out from that package's documentation to have both `2020-112-01` as the value of `\today` in the argument to `\hypersetup`, on the one hand, and somehow nanipulate the date so as to have the wordy form "December 1, 2020" within the body of the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error stems from the requirement that `pdfdate` needs to be in a specific format, not `<monthname> <day>, <year>`. The [`hyperxmp`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperxmp) [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/hyperxmp) mentions:

> XMP metadata can include a number of dates (in fact, timestamps, as they
> include both date and time components). `pdfdate` specifies the document date. It
> is analogous to the LaTeX `\date` command, and, like `\date`, defaults to the date
> the document was built. It must be specified in either XMP format or PDF
> format.

Your date format doesn't match either of these. As you found, including [`datetime2`](//ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) fixes this as it suddenly conforms to the PDF date format. However, in order to get your desired in-document date display, you need to redefine the date format. Here's how:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datetime2}
\DTMusemodule{english}{en-US}

\usepackage{hyperxmp} % to add metadata info into pdf
\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
  pdftitle = {A title},
  pdfauthor = {An author},
  pdfapart = 2,
  pdfaconformance = U,
  pdfdate = {\today}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% Set a new date style/representation
\DTMnewdatestyle{usdate}{%
  % \DTMdisplaydate{<year>}{<month>}{<day>}{<day of week>}
  \renewcommand{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{%
    \DTMenglishmonthname{##2} \number##3, \number##1 }%
   \renewcommand{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}% Capitalization of \DTMdisplaydate
}
\DTMsetdatestyle{usdate}% Use the above-defined date for date representation within the document

\begin{document}

\today

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That redefinition of `\DTMdisplaydate` has one problem: when in the body of the document the command `\today` is executed, it erroneously prints a new paragraph consisting of just a comma.

Comment: @murray: That's unrelated to the date setting. You need to supply addition PDF-related entries, like `pdftitle` and `pdfauthor` (at least). I've updated my answer to include that.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out, too. Thanks for your datetime2 solution. Digging through the package's documentation wasn't easy, with too few examples. (The thoughtful documenter includes plenty of examples along with the bare-bones reference marerial.)

Comment: The spurious comma-only paragraph seems to be caused *not* by the redefinition of `\DTMdisplaydate` but rather by my omitting from the MWE some necessary items in the `\hypersetup` arguments consistent with `hyperxmp`, namely, `pdftitle` and `pdfauthor`. With those items included, the comma-only paragraph disappears.